# Apache: You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: permissions, apache2

[image]

I am getting this on my website. I then check the usergroup for apache and to the dir of root of project

[image]

and

[image]

apache configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin rajanlagah@gmail.com
  ServerName beta.--.com
  ServerAlias beta.--.com
  DocumentRoot /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/beta-frontend/build

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Better to look at apache2 error log file. Typically at: `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: Thankyou for this i will look to it shortly. @FedonKadifeli

Comment: Your normal user may have `read` access to this directory (`DocumentRoot`). But, `apache2` daemon runs under user `www-data` (by default) and the `www-data` user may not have `read` access to this directory. Run the following command `sudo su --shell /bin/bash --login www-data`, then go to directory `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/beta-frontend/build` and try to list its contents.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Nothing but this worked, Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the owner of the following directory `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/beta-frontend/build` to `www-data`

use following command to do so:

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/beta-frontend/build`